# Notepad++ regular expression: line does not contain certain pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following list of objects:

```
type="user" N="ag12345" status="active"
type="user" N="he98745" status="active"
type="user" N="user1" status="active"
type="user" N="84566" status="active"
type="user" N="iu78965" status="active"
```

I need to find the lines where the tag "N" does not match the pattern @@#####. In other words A valid user has to be created as two consecutive alphabetic characters and 5 numbers. 
The regular expression I am looking for should show me the lines:

```
type="user" N="user1" status="active"
type="user" N="84566" status="active"
```

I've tried many many things but I can't seem to understand how to do this.

One of my attempts was: 
Find what:

```
type=user" N="(?![\l]{2}[\d]{5})" status="active"
```

and also:

```
type=user" N="(?![\l]{2})(?![\d]{5})" status="active"
```

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Note that your question could be simplified tremendously... The question doesn't have much to do with notepad++, and it has even less to do with a 'list of objects'... You are simply trying to find lines that don't match a given pattern... personally i'd like for a way to look to negate a search for a line that DOES match the pattern. But that's just me.

Comment: If you are trying to learn regex, try reading http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Use `[a-z]`  instead of `[\l]`, `\l` won't match any lowercase letters. If you want to deal with both upper and lowercase then use `[a-zA-Z]` .

```
type="user" N="(?![a-z]{2}\d{5}")[^"]*" status="active"
```

`[^"]*`, negated character class which matches any character but not of `"`, zero or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qJ3mB4/5)

Comment: Worked perfectly! thanks so much! Although I didn't understand what is the [^"]*" doing  or why \d doesn't need the brackets.

Comment: you don't need to include `\d` inside the brackets. `\d=[\d]`. Since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I was waiting for the 5-10 minutes to accept it XD. I don't have enough reputation to vote for it though. Done, and thanks again